# Cannot log on to my router with Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, router, windows-8.1

I don't know if this has anything to do with the Windows 8.1 operating system, but I cannot pingback or log on to my router (gateway). Also the gateway address info won't show up with ipconfig command. I've changed multiples routers and won't work anyway. I can access the Internet however.

Any idea how to fix it?

Following is the output of `ipconfig /all` command
(Note that the description has been roughly translated into English)

```
D:\Users\JHPC>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration
   Host name  . . . . . . . . . . . . . : JinhongPC
   Primary DNS suffix . . . . . . . . . . . :
   Point type  . . . . . . . . . . . . : Mixed
   IP Router is running . . . . . . . . . . : No
   WINS proxy is running . . . . . . . . . : No

PPP Adapter Broadband Connection:
   Connect to specific DNS suffix . . . . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadband connection
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP is running . . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Auto configuration is running. . . . . . . . . . : No
   IPv4 address . . . . . . . . . . . . : 175.155.94.167(primary)
   Subnet mask  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default gateway. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
   DNS server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 221.10.98.10
                                      119.6.6.6
   TCPIP 上的 NetBIOS  . . . . . . . : Disabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:
   Connect to specific DNS suffix . . . . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Series controller
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-26-18-B5-CC-6C
   DHCP is running . . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Auto configuration is running. . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Local connection IPv6 address. . . . . . . . : fe80::30aa:c15e:954:64b4%3(primary)
   IPv4 address . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1(primary)
   Subnet mask  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default gateway. . . . . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 50341400
   DHCPv6 Client DUID  . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-7B-CF-7F-00-26-18-B5-CC-6C

   DNS Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   TCPIP 上的 NetBIOS  . . . . . . . : Running

Channel Adapter isatap.{17FF75C1-64BB-4D7A-BE79-97CBE1E68B53}:

   Media Status  . . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connect to specific DNS suffix . . . . . . . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP is running . . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Auto configuration is running. . . . . . . . . . : Yes

Channel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Connect to specific DNS suffix. . . . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP is running . . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Auto configuration is running. . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 address . . . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:af9b:5ea7::af9b:5ea7(Primary)
   Default gateway. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:c058:6301::1
                                       2002:c058:6301::c058:6301
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 419430400
   DHCPv6 Client DUID  . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-7B-CF-7F-00-26-18-B5-CC-6C

   DNS Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 221.10.98.10
                                       119.6.6.6
   TCPIP 上的 NetBIOS  . . . . . . . : Disabled

Channel Adapter isatap.{15F260E3-200C-424A-B20E-2B12F95E7B2C}:

   Media status  . . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connect to specific DNS suffix . . . . . . . :
   Description. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical address. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP is running . . . . . . . . . . . : No

   Auto configuration is running. . . . . . . . . . : YES
```

Answer (score 0):

You do have a gateway address but you appear to be using IPv6.

```
Default gateway. . . . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:c058:6301::1
```

Using https://isc.sans.edu/tools/ipv6.html#form we can covert to IPv4:

```
Fully expanded form of the IPv6 Address: 2002:c058:6301:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
Decimal Representation: 42549581684196800060080604804048280064

The IPv6 address you entered starts with 2002 and may be a valid 6-to-4 address.

The corresponding IPv4 address is 192.88.99.1
```

So your Gateway address would appear to be `192.88.99.1`

Your Ethernet address details:

```
   IPv4 address . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1(primary)
   Subnet mask  . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
```

So somehow you are on a different subnet to your gateway? Are you connected to some kind of WAN? Corporate or college network?

Did you assign `192.168.137.1` yourself as a fixed IP address?

Comment: Hi,David,I'm on a home network (directly connect to the Internet with the router) and I'm able to pingback 192.168.137.1, but cannot access it with IE or Chrome. I didn't assign 192.168.137.1 as fixed IP address.

Comment: `192.168.137.1` is **your** pc ip address. The gateway is `192.88.99.1` which **should** be your router address.

Comment: Have you tried disabling IPv6 on your PC?

Comment: Tried uninstall IPv6 and doesn't seem to work. I think it indeed has something to do with the 8.1 operating system, because when I switch to the XP(I have a dual boot system),I'm able see my gateway address as 192.168.1.1 again and can pingback and access it. I just don't know what exactly is wrong with the settings in Win 8.1.